# Run Twisted reactor from a Thread

Tags: multithreading, twisted.internet

When i run reactor from thread in a synchrone python program, the twisted code is never called.

To resolve this problem, I had to put a sleep.

```
def _reactor_thread(self):
    if not self.reactor.running:
        self.reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0)


def _start_thread( self ):

    self.client_thread = Thread( target=self._reactor_thread,
                                 name="mine" )
    self.client_thread.setDaemon(True)
    self.client_thread.start()
    from time import sleep
    sleep( 0.5 )
```

What is the best way to do it, instead of calling sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with [Crochet](http://crochet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Or with using [addSystemEventTrigger](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#addSystemEventTrigger).